# How to prevent UINavigationController from changing back button on pushViewController:

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Is it possible to prevent the UINavigationController from changing the backBarButtonItem when pushing a view controller? I have set a custom image in the back buttons place , and I wish to keep it there. (I am making an application drawer / hamburger menu)

I have tried with the following code, but it doesn't change it back

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[centerViewController navigationItem] backBarButtonItem];

 [navigationController pushViewController:leftViewController animated:false completion:^{

    [[centerViewController navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
 }
```

Comment: you will have to reset backbutton item's image to your ham burger icon everytime a viewcontroller is pushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say if you are pushing View2 from View1 then on the view did load method of View1 set a custom back button like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]
                               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target: nil action: nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the backBarButtonItem before you push the new controller.

Example that shows the backarrow of the backBarButton without text in the newly pushed ViewController:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                           target:nil
                                                                           action:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
```